# error while building jax from source on windows

Tags: python, visual-studio, build-tools, jax

i'm trying to build jax from source on windows, when i follow the steps on https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/developer.html and run

```
python .\build\build.py
```

I get the error

```
ERROR: C:/users/user/_bazel_user/3fmegsfs/external/flatbuffers/src/BUILD.bazel:53:11: Compiling src/idl_gen_lobster.cpp failed: (Exit 1): vc_installation_error_x64.bat failed: error executing command
  cd /d C:/users/user/_bazel_user/3fmegsfs/execroot/__main__
  SET INCLUDE=msvc_not_found
    SET PATH=msvc_not_found
    SET PWD=/proc/self/cwd
    SET RUNFILES_MANIFEST_ONLY=1
    SET TEMP=msvc_not_found
    SET TMP=msvc_not_found
  external\local_config_cc\vc_installation_error_x64.bat /nologo /DCOMPILER_MSVC /DNOMINMAX /D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /bigobj /Zm500 /EHsc /wd4351 /wd4291 /wd4250 /wd4996 /Iexternal/flatbuffers /Ibazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/external/flatbuffers /Ibazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/external/flatbuffers/src/_virtual_includes/flatc /Ibazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/external/flatbuffers/src/_virtual_includes/flatc_library /Ibazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/external/flatbuffers/src/_virtual_includes/flatbuffers /Ibazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/external/flatbuffers/grpc/src/compiler/_virtual_includes/cpp_generator /Ibazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/external/flatbuffers/_virtual_includes/flatbuffers /Ibazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/external/flatbuffers/grpc/src/compiler/_virtual_includes/go_generator /Ibazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/external/flatbuffers/grpc/src/compiler/_virtual_includes/java_generator /Ibazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/external/flatbuffers/grpc/src/compiler/_virtual_includes/python_generator /Ibazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/external/flatbuffers/grpc/src/compiler/_virtual_includes/python_generator_private /Ibazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/external/flatbuffers/grpc/src/compiler/_virtual_includes/swift_generator /Ibazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/external/flatbuffers/grpc/src/compiler/_virtual_includes/ts_generator /showIncludes /MD /O2 /Oy- /DNDEBUG /wd4117 -D__DATE__="redacted" -D__TIMESTAMP__="redacted" -D__TIME__="redacted" /Gy /Gw /D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -DWIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN -DNOGDI /Zc:preprocessor -DMLIR_PYTHON_PACKAGE_PREFIX=jaxlib.mlir. /std:c++17 /Fobazel-out/x64_windows-opt/bin/external/flatbuffers/src/_objs/flatc/idl_gen_lobster.obj /c external/flatbuffers/src/idl_gen_lobster.cpp
# Configuration: 55ba85b9103400bcca86968b88fded4983bd3307407d5043544ce61b2cd80103
# Execution platform: @local_execution_config_platform//:platform

The target you are compiling requires Visual C++ build tools.
Bazel couldn't find a valid Visual C++ build tools installation on your machine.

Visual C++ build tools seems to be installed at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\HostX64\x86
But Bazel can't find the following tools:
    VCVARSALL.BAT, cl.exe, link.exe, lib.exe, ml64.exe
for x64 target architecture

Please check your installation following https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/windows.html#using

Target //build:build_wheel failed to build
```

I've checked and the files that Bazel can't find are in the path indicated. How can I solve it? Thanks

I've tried changing the environment variable but it doesn't work

Comment: It looks like this answer may be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56970693/why-bazel-does-not-find-visual-c-build-tools